# Refactorizar codigo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lógica

Estuve realizando un ejercicio de lógica de javascript y llegué a un resultado, pero quisiera saber si a alguien se le ocurre una manera más óptima de resolverlo, ya que creo que mi solución no es la mejor, ya que estoy utilizando muchos bucles, recién estoy comenzando, así que si alguien puede guiarme hacia una mejor forma, le estaría muy agradecido, muchas gracias.

Adjunto mi resolución:

````
// Crear una función que reciba un array de logs y un número máximo de minutos que 
un usuario puede estar conectado. La función debe devolver un array con los ids de 
los usuarios que cumplan con la condición de que su tiempo de conexión no supere el 
máximo de minutos.
    
    function processLogs(logs, maxSpan) {
      maxSpan = 20;
      logs = [
        "30 99 sign-in",
        "30 105 sign-out",
        "12 100 sign-in",
        "20 80 sign-in",
        "12 120 sign-out",
        "20 101 sign-out",
        "21 110 sign-in",
      ];
    
      //Creo arrays vacíos para almacenar los datos de los usuarios
      let users = [],
        ids = [],
        times = [],
        actions = [],
        timeSpent = [],
        result = [];
    
        //Recorro el array de logs y lo separo en arrays de usuarios
      for (let i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
        users.push(logs[i].split(" "));
      }
    
      //Recorro el array de usuarios y los separo en arrays de ids, times y actions
      for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        ids.push(users[i][0]);
        times.push(users[i][1]);
        actions.push(users[i][2]);
      }
    
      //Recorro los arrays de ids y actions y comparo los ids de los usuarios que hicieron sign-in con los ids de los usuarios que hicieron sign-out, si coinciden, calculo el tiempo que estuvieron conectados y lo almaceno en el array timeSpent
      for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (actions[i] == "sign-in") {
            //Recorro el array de ids y actions para comparar el id del usuario que hizo sign-in con los ids de los usuarios que hicieron sign-out
          for (let j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
            //Si el id del usuario que hizo sign-in coincide con el id de un usuario que hizo sign-out, calculo el tiempo que estuvo conectado y lo almaceno en el array timeSpent
            if (ids[i] == ids[j] && actions[j] == "sign-out") {
              timeSpent.push(times[j] - times[i]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    
    
      //Recorro el array de tiempos y si el tiempo es menor que el máximo de minutos que un usuario puede estar conectado, almaceno el id del usuario en el array result
      for (let i = 0; i < timeSpent.length; i++) {
        if (timeSpent[i] < maxSpan) {
          result.push(ids[i]);
        }
      }
    
      return result;
    }
    
    console.log(processLogs());```
````

Answer (score 2):

Algo así te podría servir

```js
    function processLogs(logs, maxSpan) {
      maxSpan = 20;
      logs = [
        '30 99 sign-in',
        '30 105 sign-out',
        '12 100 sign-in',
        '20 80 sign-in',
        '12 120 sign-out',
        '20 101 sign-out',
        '21 110 sign-in',
      ];
    
      // Crea un objeto para almacenar los tiempos de inicio de sesión de cada usuario
      let sessionTimes = {};
    
      // Recorre el arreglo de logs y almacena los tiempos de inicio de sesión en el objeto sessionTimes
      for (let i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
        let log = logs[i].split(' ');
        let id = log[0];
        let time = log[1];
        let action = log[2];
    
        if (action === 'sign-in') {
          sessionTimes[id] = time;
        }
      }
    
      // Crea un arreglo para almacenar los ids de los usuarios que han iniciado sesión durante menos de maxSpan minutos
      let result = [];
    
      // Recorre el arreglo de logs y comprueba si cada usuario ha iniciado sesión durante menos de maxSpan minutos
      for (let i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
        let log = logs[i].split(' ');
        let id = log[0];
        let time = log[1];
        let action = log[2];
    
        if (action === 'sign-out' && sessionTimes[id] && time - sessionTimes[id] < maxSpan) {
          result.push(id);
        }
      }
    
      return result;
    }
    
    console.log(processLogs());
```

Answer (score 1):

Usaría un objeto para reformatear `logs`.
Y también usa ese objeto para calcular el tiempo.

Luego, extraer una identificación de usuario en función del tiempo empleado es simple.

**EDIT**
Revisando mi respuesta... Me doy cuenta de que todavia se puede acortar.

```js
const logs = [
  "30 99 sign-in",
  "30 105 sign-out",
  "12 100 sign-in",
  "20 80 sign-in",
  "12 120 sign-out",
  "20 101 sign-out",
  "21 110 sign-in",
];

function processLogs(logs, maxSpan) {

  // Reformatear los registros como un objeto
  let logObject = {}
  logs.map((log => {
    const [id, time, action] = log.split(" ")
    if(!logObject[id]){
      logObject[id] = {}
    }
    logObject[id][action] = parseInt(time)
  }))

  // Obtener una array de ID de usuario
  const userIds = Object.keys(logObject)
  
  // Extraiga las id de los usuarios que han gastado más de maxSpan
  return userIds.map((user) => {
    if(logObject[user]["sign-out"] && (logObject[user]["sign-out"] - logObject[user]["sign-in"]) < maxSpan){
      return user
    }
    return null
  }).filter((user) => user)
}

console.log(processLogs(logs, 20));
```

[CodePen v2](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ExpKwxr?editors=0012)

---

### Respuesta original:

```js
const logs = [
  "30 99 sign-in",
  "30 105 sign-out",
  "12 100 sign-in",
  "20 80 sign-in",
  "12 120 sign-out",
  "20 101 sign-out",
  "21 110 sign-in",
];

function processLogs(logs, maxSpan) {

  // Reformatear los registros como un objeto
  let logObject = {}
  logs.map((log => {
    const [id, time, action] = log.split(" ")
    if(!logObject[id]){
      logObject[id] = {}
    }
    logObject[id][action] = parseInt(time)
  }))
  console.log(logObject)

  // Obtener una array de ID de usuario
  const userIds = Object.keys(logObject)
  
  // Calcule el tiempo empleado por cada usuario si se desconecta.
  userIds.forEach((user) => {
    if(logObject[user]["sign-out"]){
      logObject[user].timeSpent = logObject[user]["sign-out"] - logObject[user]["sign-in"]
    }
  })
  console.log(logObject)
  
  // Extraiga las id de los usuarios que han gastado más de maxSpan
  return userIds.map((user) => {
    if(logObject[user].timeSpent && logObject[user].timeSpent < maxSpan){
      return user
    }
    return null
  }).filter((user) => user)
}

console.log(processLogs(logs, 20));
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MWBaMLo?editors=001)